# Thanks vs Thank you vs Thank you so much?

Tags: phrase-usage, politeness, formality

What is the correct way to say "thanks" to anyone in any situation?

Does it make any difference depending on context or situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various levels of showing **gratitude** verbally (in order of formality)

> **Ta** *(BrE)*
>   **Thanks** *(AmE, BRE)*, **Cheers** *(BrE)*
>   **Thank you** *(AmE, BrE)*
>   **Thank you very much** *(AmE, BrE)*
>   **Many thanks** *(BrE)*
>   **Thank you very much indeed** *(BrE)*, **Many thanks** ***indeed*** *(BrE)*

The **standard expression** when something **has been done for you** is

> **Thank You** *(with eye contact and a smile)*

it is **polite** and **formal** and can be used for **any occasion**.

**Thanks** is **less formal** and can be said **casually**
**Cheers** is similar to **thanks** and used extensively in Britain
**Ta** is even more colloquial and used when also saying goodbye

> Look forward to seeing you again mate, **ta** *(as he waves and walks off)*

**Thank you very much** shows abundant gratitude as in [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dkq7WZTzkLQ) (song starts around (00:55)

In situations when one would say "thank you" **once**, like after a dinner party

> **Thank you very much** for inviting me, I really enjoyed myself
>   **Thank you very much** for driving me to the airport
>   **Thank you very much** for your kind present

In situations where "thank you" might be used **multiple times**, as in a restaurant, **the standard "thank you" should be used**.  For example, each time one's water glass is topped up. It's best not to overly use **very much**.

**Brits** may add **indeed** when something nice has been done for them which was not requested

> P1: Excuse me, you forgot your hat
>   P2: Oh, **thank you very much indeed**
>
> P1: I took the liberty of ordering you a cab to get home
>   P2: **Many thanks indeed**

Other expressions can be added to **thank you** when appropriate

> Thank you **from the bottom of my heart**
>   Thank you **that's very kind of you**
>   Thank you **kindly**
>   Thank you **much obliged** *(used in Southern AmE)*

and even

> **Thank you**, **thank you**, **thank you**!

Children in Britain are told to

> **Mind your P's and Q's** !
>   *Mind your pleases and thank yous*

You can never go wrong saying "**Thank you**"

Comment: Hi @peter, is there any difference b/w `'thanks'` and `'thanks!'` ?

Comment: "**thanks!**" has more enthusiasm than "**thanks**".  The "**!**" in "Thank you, thank you, thank you!" applies to all three "thank you"s

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the difference between those variants is level of formality and level of gratitude.

"Thanks" is less formal than "thank you"

And "many thanks", "thanks a lot" or "thank you so much" express more gratitude than "thanks" and "thank you"